# TOAD 13 Upgrade: Select into causes "numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" error

Tags: oracle, toad

After upgrading from TOAD v12 to v13 the execute as script (F5) functionality throws "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small" on the following script:

```
VAR v_analyzed VARCHAR2(10); 

EXEC SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX( LAST_ANALYZED) ) INTO : v_analyzed FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS;

TTITLE ALL_TABS
SELECT *
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TRUNC(LAST_ANALYZED) =  TO_DATE (:v_analyzed);

TTITLE ANALYZED_DATE
SELECT :v_analyzed AS ANALYZED FROM DUAL;
```

v12 gives me nice tabs below using the TTITLE as the tab label.

Answer (score 0):

`PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small` occurs anywhere you declare a string variable to be a fixed length and your code tries to assign a value whose length exceeds the declared length.

The only place you have declared a string variable is `v_analyzed` and you declared it to have a length of 10 characters. What happens if you change it to a larger size, say 32 characters? I think you'll see the problem go away.

What's happened in this case is that most likely the upgrade from Toad 12 to 13 also changed your Oracle client version or default settings. When you call `to_char()` on a date and do not specify a format, Oracle uses your client's default date format settings. Without seeing your specific setup, I am guessing that the Toad 13 default format for dates is different from Toad 12 and is producing a string longer than 10 characters.

In my experience it is best to always specify the date format when calling `to_char()` to prevent any weirdness introduced by varying default format settings.

Comment: I tested with 100 and 1000 characters.  I got the same result.   Both version are using Oraclient12Home.

Comment: Definitely not what I expected to hear. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: " I got the same result".  Nevertheless, you should _ALWAYS_ supply a format mask with your uses of to_char()

Comment: Likewise, you should *always* supply a format mask when using `TO_DATE`.

Comment: @mikeinman I was able to recreate the error but when I increased the size of `v_analyzed` to an extremely large size (320000), it worked fine. I'm using Toad v14.